# Apache Pig - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig

Been trying to simple load mongodb collection and dump it in bash, but I am getting this er. Couldn't find any solution for this one. My code:

```
grunt> REGISTER /home/thomasjsk/me/mongo-java-driver-2.13.1.jar
grunt> REGISTER /home/thomasjsk/me/mongo-hadoop-r1.3.2/core/build/libs/mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.2.jar
grunt> REGISTER /home/thomasjsk/me/mongo-hadoop-r1.3.2/pig/build/libs/mongo-hadoop-pig-1.3.2.jar


grunt> raw = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/agile_data.email' using com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader();
2015-04-20 14:28:00,123 [main] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage - Initializing MongoLoader in dynamic schema mode.
2015-04-20 14:28:00,199 [main] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage - Initializing MongoLoader in dynamic schema mode.
grunt> dump raw
2015-04-20 14:28:07,510 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-04-20 14:28:07,543 [main] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage - Initializing MongoLoader in dynamic schema mode.
2015-04-20 14:28:07,578 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2015-04-20 14:28:07,650 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]}
2015-04-20 14:28:07,903 [main] INFO  com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage - Initializing MongoLoader in dynamic schema mode.
2015-04-20 14:28:07,906 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected
```

I can load a file and dump it normally, this one occures only while I'm trying to mess with mongo.

[ Pig v0.13.0 ]

Comment: What's your hadoop version? Are you getting the same error when using [Fixed Schema](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Pig-Usage#from-a-mongodb-collection) ?

Comment: The thing is - I'm running this locally without hadoop installed, so I assumed that there can't be any hadoop compatibility issues here. Or am I wrong?

Comment: running using com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader('id:chararray, from:chararray, to:chararray, subject:chararray, body:chararray'); - gives the same error.

Comment: This might help. From Mongo-Hadoop Wiki [FAQ](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/FAQ#javalangincompatibleclasschangeerror-found-class-xxx-but-interface-was-expected)

Comment: Thanks! mongo-java-driver 3.0.0 fixed the problem, but it raised another one instead:
    ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. com/mongodb/binding/ReadBinding

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/binding/ReadBinding